# Deploying AngularJs + Sinatra to AWS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, sinatra

I have an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) site consuming an API written in [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com).

I'm simply trying to deploy these 2 components together on an [AWS EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2) instance.

How would one go about doing that? What tools do you recommend? What structure do you think is most suitable?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based upon my experience of utilizing the [HashciCorp](https://www.hashicorp.com/) line of tools.

Manual: Launch an Ubuntu image, `gem install sinatra` and deploy your code. Take a snapshot for safe keeping. This one off approach is good for a development box to iron out the configuration process. Write down the commands you run and any options you may need.

Automated: Use the [Packer](https://packer.io/) [EC2 Builder](https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html) and [Shell Provisioner](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html) to automate your commands from the previous manual approach. This will give you a configured AMI that can be launched.

You can apply different methods of getting to an AMI using different toolsets. However, in the end, you want a single immutable image that can be deployed. repeatedly.

Comment: Is it possible for me to deploy both applications to the same instance using using said tools?

Comment: Sure. The Packer Shell Provisioner is really just running the commands on your behalf on the EC2 instance. Your code would need to uploaded to the instance. For that packer has a file upload provisioner. If you zip your app you can place it on the box, say in `/tmp` and run the commands to deploy.